# Setting default value during binary operation when value doesn't exist

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have 2 metrics and first metric doesn't always exist. In cases when it doesn't exist I want to behave as it had a value `0` (or result to have a value `0`)

Metrics:

```
metric_1{label=1} 10
...
metric_2{label=1} 2
metric_2{label=2} 5
...
```

Operation:

```
metric_1 / metric_2
```

Result:

```
{label=1} 5
```

Expected:

```
{label=1} 5
{label=2} 0
```

My real-life example has many labels so creating a static vector with `{label=2}` doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use the following query:

```
(metric_1 or metric_2 * 0) / metric_2
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.